# How to Remove 'Managed by Your Organisation' Notifications in a Custom-Built Chromium Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I'm working on a custom-built Chromium browser, and I have successfully managed to implement certain policies, including forced extension installation. However, this has led to the display of "Managed by your organisation" notifications in several places within the browser.

I've attempted to locate the specific part of the Chromium source code responsible for this message by searching for the string "Managed by your organisation" within the codebase. While I have identified the purpose of these notifications as security features to inform users of enforced policies, I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact locations in the code where these messages are triggered.

I'm looking to suppress or remove these notifications from my custom build, while maintaining all other functionalities. I understand that this may be in conflict with best practices for user transparency, but I'd like to explore options, even if it requires altering the source code.

Could someone guide me to the specific locations in the Chromium source code responsible for these notifications, and suggest a method to remove or suppress them without impacting other functionalities? Any insights into potential legal or ethical considerations related to these modifications would also be greatly appreciated.

A few things to consider:

- The notifications themselves are expected to appear since I added a policy through the registry at `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Chromium\ExtensionInstallForcelist`.
- The spelling "organisation" in my post reflects how it appears in the browser, so it's intentional and not a typo.

Images from the browser:

`[3-dots-menu-with-"managed"-notification]`
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gltlJ.png)
`["managed"-notification-on-bookmarks-page]`
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWAQO.png)
`["managed"-notification-on-downloads-page]`
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge5wx.png)

Comment: It's in [GetManagedUiMenuItemLabel](https://crsrc.org/chrome/browser/ui/managed_ui.cc?q=symbol%3Achrome%3A%3AGetManagedUiMenuItemLabel). The look-up method: 1. find the text, determine its mnemonic ID like IDS_MANAGED in this case, then look for it, optionally limiting the scope via `lang:cpp` search operator.